# SSRS URL Action Lowercases Parts of the URL

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Overall Goal: Deliver an SSRS report via email (MHTML in the body of the email) that will be viewed on a mobile device. We have to use Good for Enterprise for work so that is only email client in scope here (although I am not sure if the email client is ultimately the issue here). The email will have links embedded inside that should open up the Salesforce1 app (via the URL scheme in iOS) and take the user to a specific record in the app.

I am trying to create an action on a placeholder to go to a URL. The URL in question is

```
salesforce1://sObject/<id>/view
```

This works fine in regards to generating a valid URL. However the `sObject` piece gets automatically converted to lowercase `sobject` in the resulting MHTML/PDF/etc. outputs.

For what I need the `sObject` section needs to have the capital `O` as that is what the Salesforce1 iOS app is expecting (no idea why lowercase will not work but it doesn't and that has been confirmed in my testing).

The funny thing is I can capitalize `VIEW` and that remains capitalized in the output. It is just the `sObject` part getting converted to lowercase.

It doesn't matter if I LCase and UCase the strings or build the URL directly in the dataset or anything else. SSRS is always lowercasing the `sobject` part.

Any thoughts? I am out of ideas.

UPDATE:

It appears that SSRS is lowercasing everything to the left of the ID in my example below. That includes the `salesrforce1://` and anything in `sobject`. Must be some SSRS "feature".

Screenshots below.

Report Design
[image: Report Design]

Placeholder Properties
[image]

Dataset Query (for the field in question)
[image]

Resulting report output when run

[image]

The HTML code created when exporte to MHTML (notice part of the ID is capitalized)
[image]

Comment: Can you add some screenshots of your report design and rendered so we can see what you are doing and what the output is?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but try using JS for the action `="javascript:void(window.open('salesforce1://sObject/<id>/view', '_blank'))"`

Comment: I was really hoping the javascript method was going to work. It doesn't fire the Salesforce1 app to open on iOS (at least with Good for Enterprise email client that we have to use). When you tap the link nothing happens.